# Dropdown selection to countdown- changes constantly

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

Sorry for the poor title, not really sure how to title it.

However the problem that is occurring: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLp4mtog/3/)

Whenever selecting multiple values from the dropdown (one after another) without refreshing, the countdowns will flash between each other constantly.

HTML:

```
<div id="countdown">Please select a value</div>
<select id="Dropdown" onchange="Run()">
  <option value="50">Nothing</option>
  <option value="1">Re:Zero kara Hajimeru Isekai Seikatsu</option>
  <option value="2">Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress</option>
  <option value="3">Boku no Hero Academia</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function Run() {
  var _s = document.getElementById("Dropdown");
  var s = _s.options[_s.selectedIndex].value;

  if (s == 50) {
    var end = new Date('02/25/2016 00:00 AM');
  } else if (s == 3) {
    var end = new Date('05/22/2016 6:30 PM');
  } else if (s == 2) {
    var end = new Date('05/20/2016 9:00 AM');
  } else if (s == 1) {
    var end = new Date('05/23/2016 3:00 AM')
  }


  var _second = 1000;
  var _minute = _second * 60;
  var _hour = _minute * 60;
  var _day = _hour * 24;
  var timer;

  function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;

    if (distance < 0) {

      clearInterval(timer);
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "It's out already ;)";

      return;
    }

    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ' days, ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, ' + seconds + ' seconds.';

  }

  timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

  if (s == 50) {
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Don't select nothing ;)"
end;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time `Run()` is called on dropdown `change`, the function creates a new `timer` variable. (*Variables in JavaScript have function level scope. They are garbage collected once they are out of scope*). So, in your code, `clearInterval(timer)` would never be called successfully (log will show undefined) since `timer` is out of `scope` when you change the dropdown.

So make the `timer` global and call `clearInterval` on every `change` like below:

```js
var timers; // Make a global timer variable

function Run() {
  console.log(timers); // Observe it holds the previous timer value
  clearInterval(timers); // clear interval here everytime 



  var _s = document.getElementById("Dropdown");
  var s = _s.options[_s.selectedIndex].value;

  if (s == 50) {
    var end = new Date('02/25/2016 00:00 AM');
  } else if (s == 3) {
    var end = new Date('05/22/2016 6:30 PM');
  } else if (s == 2) {
    var end = new Date('05/20/2016 9:00 AM');
  } else if (s == 1) {
    var end = new Date('05/23/2016 3:00 AM')
  }


  var _second = 1000;
  var _minute = _second * 60;
  var _hour = _minute * 60;
  var _day = _hour * 24;


  function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;

    if (distance < 0) {

      clearInterval(timers);
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "It's out already ;)";

      return;
    }

    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ' days, ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, ' + seconds + ' seconds.';

  }

  timers = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
  console.log(timers); // observe the value set here

  if (s == 50) {
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Don't select nothing ;)"
    end;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown">Please select a value</div>
<select id="Dropdown" onchange="Run()">
  <option value="50">Nothing</option>
  <option value="1">Re:Zero kara Hajimeru Isekai Seikatsu</option>
  <option value="2">Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress</option>
  <option value="3">Boku no Hero Academia</option>
</select>
```